# How to creat links between turtles who share the same parameter?

Tags: netlogo

What's the syntax if I wanted to create links between turtles that share the same parameter value?

In this case, households are my turtles and I need households to create links with other households that share the same Social-Net parameter value.

```
  ask households [if [Social-Net] of self = [Social-Net] of one-of other households [create-link]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
breed [ households household ]
households-own [ social-net ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-households 50 [ set social-net random 10 ]
  ask households [
    create-links-with other households with [
      social-net = [ social-net ] of myself
    ]
  ]
end
```